# Como Mostar la definición una palabra

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo el típico juego del ahorcado en Python para ir aprendiendo.

Me gustaría que al mostrar la palabra, al final, me mostrase la definición de la RAE.

Entiendo que tengo que buscar la API de la RAE pero aunque he encontrado algo de documentación no soy capaz de hacerlo.

¿Alguno conoce como se hace o donde me puedo documentar?

Muchísimas gracias a todos

Comment: Tenemos que partir de algo, sería de ayuda que subas el código de lo que tienes para ver posibles errores y darle solución. También sugerir que edites la pregunta para que sea bien recibida. Mientras tanto puedes ver [ask] para que te orientes mejor.

Comment: Podrías incluir el estado de tu programa y en la parte "He encontrado algo de documentación" incluir lo que has encontrado o u link al menos.

Comment: Entiendo que la RAE no tiene una API expuesta.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado?

Comment: La información que encontré  no me ayudo mucho, la verdad. Lo que si me ayudo fue este enlace: https://es.scribd.com/document/98714329/Problemas-de-ortografia-La-R-A-E-y-Python-raudas-al-rescate

Comment: @Javier El enlace que pones al artículo en scribd es ya del 2005. Me temo que desde entonces la DRAE ha cambiado su web para hacerse "resistente" a ese tipo de scraping. Ahora sin ejecución en cliente de javascript es muy complejo sacar nada.

Comment: @abulafia al final lo voy a hacer como tu me indicas. Me parece mas fácil y ademas muy bien explicado.

De hecho lo intente pero no he podido instalar "requers". Lo tengo que ver con mas tiempo. Es que soy muy novato. Muchísimas gracias,

Comment: @Javier No es requers, sino `requests`. La forma de instalar paquetes en Python depende de qué operativo uses. Si tienes dificultades para instalarlo podrías crear una nueva pregunta al respecto

Comment: @abulafia mil gracias. Funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te han dicho, la RAE no expone una API para facilitar las consultas. Es más, parece que deliberadamente han complicado la arquitectura de su página web para evitar (o dificultar) el *scraping*, pues las consultas ajax que hace para obtener las definiciones, usan una URL diferente cada vez, generada a partir de la ejecución de javascript y de valores "magicos" enviados por el servidor.

Creo que es mejor usar otra fuente de datos. Por ejemplo, [Goodrae](http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae) proporciona una interfaz de usuario mucho más limpia y sin publicidad. Aunque tampoco proporcionan una API, el código HTML de esta página es más simple y apropiado para scraping.

Ejemplo de solicitud de una definición:

```
import requests

url = "http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/definicion.php?palabra={}&lema=no"
palabra = "ejemplo"

r = requests.get(url.format(palabra))
resultado = r.content.decode("utf8", errors="ignore")
```

El resultado es un HTML que por desgracia tampoco está muy bien estructurado, pues la parte que nos interesa (la definición) en lugar de estar dentro de un `<div>` con un `id` fácilmente localizable, está en realidad delimitada por un par de comentarios: `"<!-- Principio de contenido -->"` y `"<!-- Fin de contenido -->"`.

Además, en esa definición, cada una de las palabras que la componen es a su vez un hiper-enlace hacia otra búsqueda (para que el usuario pueda pinchar en cualquiera de las palabras y ver su definición). Esto implica que la definición está *sembrada* de tags `<a></a>` que habría que quitar para poder mostrar sólo el texto.

El siguiente fragmento python usa operaciones con cadenas para extraer el trozo donde está esa definición, y sustituir los `<br/>` que contenga por retornos de carro, así como para eliminar todo el marcado interno (mayormente `<a></a>` como se ha explicado, aunque también se perderá la negrita y la cursiva). Finalmente condensa las secuencias de varios espacios en uno solo:

```
import re

definicion = resultado.split("<!-- Principio de contenido -->")[1]
definicion = definicion.split("<!-- Fin de contenido -->")[0]
definicion = definicion.replace("<br>","\n")
definicion = re.sub("<.*?>", "", definicion)
definicion = re.sub(" +", " ", definicion)
print(definicion)
```

Para todo esto hemos usado, como se ve, python estándar y sus expresiones regulares. Quizás hubiera sido más normal usar alguna biblioteca de *scraping*, como BeautifulSoup, pero en esta página en particular, dado lo poco habitual de su marcado, creo que puede ser más sencillo hacerlo "a pelo", sin usar bibliotecas de scraping.

El resultado de ejecutar lo anterior es:

```html
ejemplo. 
 (Del lat. exemplum). 

 1. m. Caso o hecho sucedido en otro tiempo, que se propone, o bien para que se imite y siga, si es bueno y honesto, o para que se evite si es malo. 
 2. m. Acción o conducta que puede inclinar a otros a que la imiten. 
 3. m. Hecho, texto o cláusula que se cita para comprobar, ilustrar o autorizar un aserto, doctrina u opinión. 
 4. m. ant. ejemplar (‖ escrito o impreso sacado de un original). 
 ~ casero. 
 1. m. El que se toma de aquellas cosas que por ser muy comunes y frecuentes las entienden todos. 
 dar ~. 
 1. loc. verb. Excitar con las propias obras la imitación de los demás. 
 por ~. 
 1. expr. U. cuando se va a poner un ejemplo para comprobar, ilustrar o autorizar lo que antes se ha dicho. 
 sin ~. 
 1. loc. adv. Sin precedente, como caso raro.
```

Como comparación, aquí está la página tal como la muestra el navegador:

[image: Pantalla]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Muy completo, la verdad. Este fin de semana lo intento